# How to count number of substrings in python, if substrings overlap?

Tags: python-3.x, substring

The `count()` function returns the number of times a substring occurs in a string, but it fails in case of overlapping strings.

Let's say my input is:

```
^_^_^-_-
```

I want to find how many times `^_^` occurs in the string.

```
mystr=input()
happy=mystr.count('^_^')
sad=mystr.count('-_-')
print(happy)
print(sad)
```

Output is:

```
1
1
```

I am expecting:

```
2
1
```

How can I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**New Version**

You can solve this problem without writing any explicit loops using regex. As [@abhijith-pk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49293593/2988730) cleverly suggests, you can search for the first character only, with the remainder being placed in a positive lookahead, which will allow you to make the match with overlaps:

```
def count_overlapping(string, pattern):
    regex = '{}(?={})'.format(re.escape(pattern[:1]), re.escape(pattern[1:]))
    # Consume iterator, get count with minimal memory usage
    return sum(1 for _ in re.finditer(regex, string))
```

[[IDEOne Link]](https://ideone.com/vLih7t)

Using `[:1]` and `[1:]` for the indices allows the function to handle the empty string without special processing, while using `[0]` and `[1:]` for the indices would not.

**Old Version**

You can always write your own routine using the fact that [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) allows you to specify a starting index. This routine will not be very efficient, but it should work:

```
def count_overlapping(string, pattern):
    count = 0
    start = -1
    while True:
        start = string.find(pattern, start + 1)
        if start < 0:
            return count
        count += 1
```

[[IDEOne Link]](https://ideone.com/dWTdSw)

**Usage**

Both versions return identical results. A sample usage would be:

```
>>> mystr = '^_^_^-_-'
>>> count_overlapping(mystr, '^_^')
2
>>> count_overlapping(mystr, '-_-')
1
>>> count_overlapping(mystr, '')
9
>>> count_overlapping(mystr, 'x')
0
```

Notice that the empty string is found `len(mystr) + 1` times. I consider this to be intuitively correct because it is effectively between and around every character.

Answer (score 3):

you can use regex for a quick and dirty solution :

```
import re
mystr='^_^_^-_-'
print(len(re.findall('\^(?=_\^)',mystr)))
```

Comment: This is awesome. Search for first character, positive lookahead on the rest. May I steal and generalize it?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes , Please and thanks for for explaining it nicely :)

Comment: I knew one of the regex ninjas will come out and post better answer :-)

Comment: I am a newbie to python and hence having a tough time in understanding this code. Can you please explain re.findall() and it's first argument? Thank you.

Comment: @Abhijithpk. See the update to my answer. Seems to work like the crap I posted before, but so much more elegant. Thanks for showing me this

Comment: @AyushGoyal Have a look at MadPhysicist 's updated answer ,He is explaining how positive lookahead works and he uses re.escape to avoid escaping regex special characters like ^ instead of my crude backslash escape sequence

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this

```
def count_substr(string,substr):
    n=len(substr)
    count=0
    for i in range(len(string)-len(substr)+1):
        if(string[i:i+len(substr)] == substr):      
            count+=1
    return count

mystr=input()
print(count_substr(mystr,'121'))
```

> Input:  12121990
>
> Output: 2

Comment: This is a totally functional solution, but it has a number of inefficiencies. The main one is that `string[i:i+len(substr)]` creates a new string object every single time.

Comment: totally agree with you. It's not an efficient solution but only thing I could come up with. will surly improve :-)

Comment: It's completely functional, so +1. I really don't think mine is much better, but I couldn't think of a better way either :)

Comment: I especially like that we get the same result for an empty patter without any special processing.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's ideal to return the value(len+1) where we specify empty pattern.

Comment: I think it is absolutely ideal to do that :) I even addressed it in my answer.