# How to count the number of substrings in a string?

Tags: python-3.x, string, substring

I want to find the number of occurrences  of a  particular sub-string in a string.

```
string="abcbcbcb"
sub_str="cbc"
c=string.count(sub_str)
print(c)
```

This gives the output as

```
1
```

which is the number of non-overlapping occurrences of substring in the string.
But I want to calculate the overlapping strings as well. Thus, the desired output is:

```
2
```

Comment: here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49293140/how-to-count-number-of-substrings-in-python-if-substrings-overlap or here: https://www.codespeedy.com/count-overlapping-substrings-in-a-given-string-in-python/ does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No standard function available for overlapping count. You could write custom function tho.

```
def count_occ(string, substr):
   cnt = 0
   pos = 0
   while(True):
       pos = string.find(substr , pos)
       if pos > -1:
           cnt += 1
           pos += 1
       else:
           break
   return cnt


string="abcbcbcb"
sub_str="cbc"
print(count_occ(string,sub_str))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression, use module "re"

```
print len(re.findall('(?=cbc)','abcbcbcb'))
```

Comment: This is showing error. But upon improvements it works,thanks!@Sergey Chinkov